# Org-mode tag autocomplete with helm adds unwanted comma

Tags: org-mode, helm, org-capture

When using `org-capture`, tags are auto-completed with a comma that is not compatible with `org-mode` tags (`org-mode` tags are separated by colons)

I believe `helm` is assisting with the tag autocomplete with the following:

```
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(org-capture . helm-org-completing-read-tags))
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(org-set-tags . helm-org-completing-read-tags))
```

Is there a way to tell `helm` (or another component) to exclude this tag?

This is what happens when a tag is auto-completed:

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about `helm` but the tags completion interface seems to be somewhat confusing, although I didn't follow the whole thread: see [this issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2063)

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem, but only on macOS. The commas are correctly stripped and converted to colons after pressing enter on Windows and Linux, but not macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the comma works, and is correctly converted to a colon when you hit enter. It is still a bug, because you can only complete one tag the first time you insert tags to a heading (you can still add multiple, using the comma, but I was getting "No match" when I tried to tab complete any tag past the first. Once you have one or some tags on a heading, subsequent invocations of `org-set-tags-command` use colons and tab complete as many tags as you like.

Comment: After testing this a few times, I've noticed that the comma is not converted to colon. It is included within the tag text, e.g. `:test,:`